# Ubuntu Server 16.04: Running Django on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am having troubles getting apache to run django. I am being able to run "python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.1.230:80" and it will run everything fine. But once I try to have apache run it, I will get a "500 internal server error". I have watched multiple YouTube videos and also read many articles. The main articles I have followed are: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

I am not sure what to do next. I have looked at my error.log and can't find anything to help my particular situation.

Here is my /etc/apache2/apache.conf file:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel debug

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.con

    Alias /static /home/thomasc/tportal/static
    <Directory /home/thomasc/tportal/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/thomasc/tportal/tportal>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess tportal python-home=/home/thomac/tportal/tportalenv python-path=/home/thomasc/tportal
    WSGIProcessGroup tportal
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/thomasc/tportal/tportal/wsgi.py process-group=tportal
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here is my /home/thomasc/tportal/wsgi.py file:

```
"""
WSGI config for tportal project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
import site

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/thomas/tportal')
sys.path.append('/home/thomas/tportal/tporatl')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tportal.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here is my /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Mon Jan 29 14:06:27.599927 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 5649:tid 140043045828352] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 96.42.121.40:62895] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://66.188.177.133/
[Mon Jan 29 14:06:27.599949 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 5649:tid 140043045828352] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 96.42.121.40:62895] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://66.188.177.133/
[Mon Jan 29 14:06:27.600011 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 5649:tid 140043045828352] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 96.42.121.40:62895] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://66.188.177.133/
[Mon Jan 29 14:06:27.600023 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 5649:tid 140043045828352] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 96.42.121.40:62895] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://66.188.177.133/
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.600239 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742] mod_wsgi (pid=5647, process='tportal', application='ubuntu.Fun|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/thomasc/tportal/tportal/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.601810 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742] mod_wsgi (pid=5647): Target WSGI script '/home/thomasc/tportal/tportal/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.601903 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742] mod_wsgi (pid=5647): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/thomasc/tportal/tportal/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602126 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602208 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]   File "/home/thomasc/tportal/tportal/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602221 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602244 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602256 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602278 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602289 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602311 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602323 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Mon Jan 29 20:06:27.602361 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5647:tid 140043151005440] [remote 96.42.121.40:49742] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

If you have any suggestions that would be great!!!

Comment: Go back through the logs and find the very first Python error that occurred. The ``populate() isn't reentrant`` error is a follow on error caused by Django not being able to be initialised more than once in a process. The real cause will be the first error before that, which is not that error.

Answer (score 0):

I got apache to run with django now. I created a proxy pass with apache and then I run django in the background. I have my django running on localhost:8080 and apache running on port 80. I have the configuration for apache below. To run django in the background, I created a script that will on startup, that runs my command that I use to start django. The command is "python3 /home/thomasc/SysReq/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080 &". The "&" is to run the process in the background, and since django will be always running, it makes sure no other processes get hung up. Also my Django project "SysReg" so that is why I have my path in my command, so I can reach "manage.py".

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: You should never use ``runserver`` for a production system, even if behind a proxy. It is only intended for development. At least use ``mod_wsgi-express`` behind the proxy if going to do it that way. Or just go back in the error log and find that original error to find out why it was failing in the first place.

Comment: I haven't looked at mod_wsgi-express yet but ill take a look! I am doing this website for a school project so its not technically production but kind of is at the same time!